# How to rotate image in the speedometer in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

Following is a code for rotate the arrow(uiimage) on touch event. in this i subtract the position of the two touches previous and current but problem is that the arrow(uiimage) sometime moves in a opposite direction of the touch.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];        
    NSLog(@"%@",[touch view]);   
    if ([touch view] == ImgViewArrowImage) 
    {
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    CGPoint pastLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];

    CGPoint d1 = CGPointMake(currentLocation.x-touch.view.center.x, currentLocation.y-touch.view.center.y);   
    CGPoint d2 = CGPointMake(pastLocation.x-touch.view.center.x, pastLocation.y-touch.view.center.y);

    CGFloat angle1 = atan2(d1.y, d1.x); 
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2(d2.y, d2.x); 
    [[ImgViewArrowImage layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [[ImgViewArrowImage layer] setPosition:CGPointMake(159,211)];

    ImgViewArrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(ImgViewArrowImage.transform, angle1-angle2);
  } 
}
```

Comment: it may happen when angle1-angle2 goes subzero.

Comment: ya Teodor, thats i know that subtraction goes in minus...but i need solution for that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just remove 2 lines from my code and my code is working now so the final code is

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];        
    NSLog(@"%@",[touch view]);   
    if ([touch view] == ImgViewArrowImage) 
    {
    CGPoint d1 = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    CGPoint d2 = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];


    CGFloat angle1 = atan2(d1.y, d1.x); 
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2(d2.y, d2.x); 
    [[ImgViewArrowImage layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [[ImgViewArrowImage layer] setPosition:CGPointMake(159,211)];

    ImgViewArrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(ImgViewArrowImage.transform, angle1-angle2);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the comments of the original question, **to keep the angle above 0**:

```
float _angle = angle1 - angle2;
if (_angle < 0) _angle += M_PI; // if you are working with radians, otherwise: _angle += 360.f;
```

**there would be another reason:**

we all knows how the `atan(...)` works: it is undetermined when the denominator is *zero* because dividing by *zero* is a not defined case, and the result of the `atan(...)` will be unlimited theoretically, but in the case of the `float` you might get the `MAX_FLOAT` value.

Comment: just an idea, because I had a same problem before and it caused by the second reason... I'm just seeing you don't check the parameters what you are using for the `atan(...)` function.

Comment: i think the problem is that angle is measured with the reference to main screen coordinate due to that the difference of angle getting wrong....may be thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 self.button.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(self.button.layer.anchorPoint.x, self.button.layer.anchorPoint.y*2);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[self.button setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * -40.0579987)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```